# Show navigation in React when page is scrolled to certain component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to achieve a certain effect with a navbar. The challenges I am facing are as below:

- The navigation should appear only when the user scrolls to a certain component on the website and it should work the other way around when scrolling up
- There should be a progress bar in the navigation on the scroll
- I could only find how to make that starting from the top of the website but not starting from a certain point on the website

I don't need the code, just an idea of how to approach this. Maybe there are some good libraries that could help.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `IntersectionObserver` to trigger an effect when a certain component becomes visible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla javascript we can check the body scroll height and get it like this:

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

After you get the `scrollTop` value you can just make an if statement and display navbar when scroll gets to your desired value using css properties such as `display`, `opacity` or even `height`. You can even add the transition on these properties in css:

```
.navbar: {
  transition: height 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

For the progress bar you can just make a div inside the navbar, that scales with the `scrollTop` variable. You can calculate at what percentage progress bar should be like this:

```
addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight -    document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  var progressPercent = (scrollTop / height) * 100

  console.log(progressPercent + "%");
});
```

You need event listener to update the value every time you use the scroll. In react you can do this in the `useEffect()` hook, but **don't forget to remove it in a cleanup function**, return part of `useEffect()` or you will end up with more event listeners every time you use the scroll and kill the page performance as the number of them increases. Read more about this in this [article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-cleanup-event-listeners-react).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for React's onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events on your component to show/hide your navbar and start your progress bar

```js
<Component onMouseEnter={() => {showNavBar()}} />
```

[Events Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)